# raid 5 over 12 disks and failed two hard can rebuild

Tags: dell-perc

i have installed 12 hard drives 4 TB Black Caviar make raid 5 and suddenly failed two drives at same time can rebuild raid if i replace failed drives with new drives. my data is still available  or not data is very important.

Comment: *sigh* - we get someone just like you every couple of weeks - still using R5 in 2018, worse still in your case with large SATA disks and large disk sets - R5 has been effectively dead for a decade or more - your data is lost, restore from backup and learn from this lesson.

Answer (score 2):

It's OK to use RAID5 with SSDs but you can't do RAID5 with HDDs >1TBs. Reason is simple: Slow rebuilds and very high chance of a double fault single parity RAID can't survive.